# How add value in list inside list?

Tags: python, list

python code
if I have List `[ [m,1],[n,5],[t,4] ]`

I want if I input m and add 3, return me `[m,4]`

List `[ [m,4],[n,5],[t,4] ]`

but if  I input f and add 3, return me `[f,3]`

List `[ [m,1],[n,5],[t,4] ,[f,3] ]`

This is what I do but it is wrong

---

```
main_list=[ ["m",1],["n",5],["t",4]  ]

def items_in_list(input,add):
    if any(input in sublist for sublist in main_list):
        print("we have it")
        sublist[1]= +add


    else:
        ele = [input,add]
        main.append(ele)


items=input("enter you items: ")
add=int(input("enter you add: "))
items_in_list(items,add)

print(main_list)
```

Comment: Why we are not using dictionary for this ?

Comment: Better yet, `collections.Counter`.

Comment: `collections.Counter` ftw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it you should use a dictionary not a list in this case.
You can do something like this:

```
main_dict={
    'm': 1,
    'n': 5,
    't': 4,
}

def items_in_list(input_name,to_add, main_dict):
    try:
        main_dict[input_name] += to_add
    except:
        main_dict[input_name] = to_add
```

Example 1:

```
items_in_list('m',5, main_dict)
print(main_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'m': 6, 'n': 5, 't': 4}
```

Example 2:

```
items_in_list('k',5, main_dict)
print(main_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'m': 1, 'n': 5, 't': 4, 'k': 5}
```

Comment: You should really make your function return `main_dict`. Or, just my opinion, making the dictionary a `collections.defaultdict(int)` would be more idiomatic, then you can skip the try/except.

Comment: `collections.Counter` is made for use cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you.

```py
kitchen_list=[ ['m',1],['n',5],['t',4]  ]

def items_in_list(item,add):
    if any(items in a for a in kitchen_list):
        lst = [[a[0],a[1]+add] if item in a else a for a in kitchen_list]

    else:
        lst = kitchen_list.copy()
        lst.append([item,add])        
    
    return lst

items=input("enter you items: ")
add=int(input("enter you add: "))
kitchen_list = items_in_list(items,add)
print(kitchen_list)
```

output

```py
IN: 'm', 1

OUT: [['m', 2], ['n', 5], ['t', 4]]


# -----------------------------#

IN: 'y', 12

OUT: [['m', 1], ['n', 5], ['t', 4], ['y', 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest a Python list within a Python list like so:

```
>>> plist = [["a", 1], ["b", 1]]
>>> plist[0][1]
```

The second line will output 1. Then addition would work as it usually does in Python:

```
>>> plist[0][1] += 2
>>> plist[0][1] 
3
```

Nonetheless, D. Manasreh  and Deepak already made a good point that what you are trying to achieve is better implemented with a dictionary. Yet, the answer to your question, how do you add a list within a list is what I described above, the only thing you did not do correctly is just making proper use of strings in Python, meaning you are missing "" around the characters in your list, quote:

```
List [ [m,1],[n,5],[t,4] ,[f,3] ]
```

> This is what I do but it is wrong

Yes it is, since this line would output the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'm' is not defined
```

For the list to be a Python list try:

```
[["m", 1], ["n", 5], ["t", 4], ["f", 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are handling `m, n, t` like literals but actually they are undefined variables.
A correct way of using literals in Python is enlosing literal by quotes.

```
li = [['m', 1], ['n', 5], ['t', 4]]

def add_to_group(name_group, li, increment):
    for list_element in li:
        # print(list_element)
        if list_element[0] == name_group:
            list_element[1] += increment
    return li


li = add_to_group('m', li, increment=5)
print(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

path_to_file = 'data.obj'
path = Path(path_to_file)

if path.is_file():
    print("you have data")
    fileObj = open("data.obj", 'rb')
    main_list = pickle.load(fileObj)
    fileObj.close()
else:
    print("you did not have data")
    main_list = {}
    fileObj = open("data.obj", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(kitchen_list, fileObj)
    fileObj.close()


def items_in_main(input_name,to_add, main_list):
    try:
        main_list[input_name] += to_add
    except:
        main_list[input_name] = to_add


items=input("enter you items: ")
add=int(input("enter you add: "))
items_in_main(items,add,main_list)

print(main_list)

fileObj= open("data.obj",'wb')
pickle.dump(main_list,fileObj)
fileObj.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).